# Storing files in a subdomain/custom folder using the Storage function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying at the moment to upload files onto a subdomain, hosted on the same server, while the Laravel application is hosted on the main domain. Is there any way to use the Storage functions with the subdomain? Or anything similar?

Answer (score -1):

You can use FTP to transfer file from your server to another server.

First, the receiver must have ftp account.

Second, you can use this below code to transfer your file [[source]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php).

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$remote_file = 'readme.txt';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: I'm aware of FTP being a solution, but I'm looking for something quicker. Also, I'm talking about Laravel's Storage function, so the normal FTP functions aren't really applicable here.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see that 2 laravels in the same server.